# 2GP Managed Package Installation Error: (My_Flow) A flow can’t be triggered by My_Event__e records. Change the object in the Start element

Tags: managed-package, visual-workflow, platform-event, 2gp

I have a `2PG Managed Package` which includes two `Flow` which use `Platform Event` as the starting object.

When we try and install the `Beta` package into a `Scratch Org` it fails with error:

> 1. (On_My_Flow1) A flow can’t be triggered by My_Event1__e records. Change the object in the Start element.
>    On_My_Flow1: A flow can’t be triggered by
>    My_Event1__e records. Change the object in the Start element.
> 2. (On_My_Flow2) A flow can’t be triggered by My_Event2__e records. Change the object in the Start element.
>    On_My_Flow2: A flow can’t be triggered by My_Event2__e
>    records. Change the object in the Start element.

I am confused by this, because `Platform Events` are supported as start elements in `Flow`

Then I removed one of the `Flow` and tried to create a new package version, but then I got this error:

> ERROR running force:package:version:create: My_Flow: A flow can’t be triggered by My_Event__e records. Change the object in the Start element

So now I cannot even create a new package version!

**Questions**

1. Why is this happening?
2. How do I fix it?

Comment: is there any namespace? maybe try prefixing it.

Comment: @YsrShk -  your idea allowed me to create a new package version, but it still wouldn't install into the target scratch org.

Comment: oh and is there any feature are required to use the same. Like scratch org has some features mentioned in config files. The scratch org used for development and used for testing are having same config? or any difference?

Comment: Check the flow metadata; in my experience, you do have to include the namespace prefix for anything used in the flow that comes from a namespace (even if it is the namespace for the package in which the flow is to exist).

Comment: @PhilW - We added the namespace, and were able to create the package, but then couldn't install the package, getting the same error

Comment: What API version for the flow?

Comment: @PhilW - API v52